# convert array into array with key and parenthesis in the form [{fruit:"apple"},{fruit:"banana"},{fruit:"mango}]

Tags: javascript

could you please tell me how to convert an array which is

> ["apple","banana", "mango"]

to

> [{fruit:"apple"},{fruit:"banana"},{fruit:"mango}]

with the parenthesis

something similar to this but with parenthesis
[JavaScript Add key to each value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372246/javascript-add-key-to-each-value-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still looking for [the `.map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), just like that other question.  The only difference is that you want to return an *object* from the callback, not just a string.

For example:

```js
let input = ["apple","banana", "mango"];
console.log(input.map(x => ({fruit: x})));
```

As an aside, `{}` are not parentheses, they are curly braces.

Comment: Why does this deserve its own new answer? And why is this not the nth dupe of one of the _"convert array of strings into array of objects"_ questions?